# GitLab Code Quality report not accurately displaying the code issues

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I am building a ci job that creates a custom code quality report and then publishes the artifact to the codequality report. The pipeline recognizes that there is a codequality report artifact and shows the MR widget and pipeline tab but both say `No code quality issues found`.

I have checked that the artifact is uploaded and that the JSON is valid.

Here is how the job publishes the artifact:

```bash
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - pylama.txt
      - pylama.svg
    reports:
      codequality: gl-code-quality-report.json
```

This is a sample of the JSON in the `gl-code-quality-report.json` file:

```json
[
   {
      "type": "issue",
      "check_name": "Error",
      "description": "Unexpected keyword argument 'self' in function call",
      "categories": "Error",
      "fingerprint": "7c1f2ce887b2f1e2e4c1549f6901c18f",
      "severity": "major",
      "location": {
         "path": "company_set/create_user.py",
         "lines": {
            "begin": "98"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "type": "issue",
      "check_name": "Error",
      "description": "Unexpected keyword argument 'self' in function call",
      "categories": "Error",
      "fingerprint": "7c1f2ce887b2f1e2e4c1549f6901c18f",
      "severity": "major",
      "location": {
         "path": "project/compare_data.py",
         "lines": {
            "begin": "118"
         }
      }
   },
]
```

I have verified that the path for the locations are correct and based in the root of the directory.

I have also verified that all required keys are included in each issue dictionary using [this](https://github.com/codeclimate/platform/blob/master/spec/analyzers/SPEC.md#data-types) source and [GitLabs Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#customizing-scan-settings).

Answer (score 0):

GitLab won't parse the results unless the `lines.begin` is an `integer`.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#no-code-quality-appears-on-merge-requests-when-using-custom-tool